# The moments of a probability distribution which decays through time (not normalized!)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

When one solves the diffusion equation for Brownian motion between $x=-a$ and $x=a$ with absorbing boundary conditions, the resulting probability distribution $p(x,t)$ decays through time (i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-a}^a p(x,t) dx < 0$). This decay represents the fact that particles "die" when they absorbed by one of the boundaries, so that we are not guaranteed to find a particle in the domain at all times.

I am wondering how to interpret the moments of this distribution. Assuming a particle survives, should one calculate (for instance) the mean position in the traditional way, as in
$$ \langle x (t) \rangle = \int_{-a}^a x p(x,t)dx, $$
or are the definitions of the moments modified to something like
$$ \langle x (t) \rangle = \frac{\int_{-a}^a x p(x,t)dx }{\int_{-a}^a p(x,t)dx}$$
since the probability distribution is no longer normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two different types of moments that could be of interest in these problems.

The first are the moments of the stopped process, where you think of particles are being stuck at the boundary upon first passage.  You could, of course, have alternative dynamics for what happens once particles hit the barrier.  Some examples include "rebirth" at 0, or reflection.  For these processes, because particles never leave the population, there's no need to normalize.

The other type are conditional moments, where you are only interested in the draws that haven't hit the boundary by time $t$.  For these, you of course have to normalize, otherwise the effect of the decay will dominate (for bounded processes) and it will decay towards zero irrespective of the underlying process.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Does my normalization in the second equation above make sense to you? Basically one should divide by the survival probability?

Comment: Yes, that's the right normalization.  It's exactly analogous to a conditional expectation